# Tools resolving complicated Gradle dependencies

Tags: gradle, dependencies

So I have a complicated dependency tree for one or more gradle projects / subprojects.

So I run `gradle dependencies` and it creates a big ole file ascii tree with dependencies.

But this is not very readable for my huuuuge gradle file.

Is there perhaps a tool that views this? Or a way to get a json formatted output instead?

Comment: maybe try running it for a concrete module like gradle :core-module:dependencies

Answer (score 2):

If you use IntelliJ IDEA (I'd heavily recommend to do if you code Java), there is a `Gradle View` plugin that can display the dependency tree as a clickable tree.

Other than that, you can also give the `dependencies` task a concrete configuration with `--configuration` that should be displayed, or you can use the `dependencyInsight` task if it is more that you want to know where a specific dependency comes from.

Comment: yep i'm using this tool to make it so i can load my project in intelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

It ended up that I really needed a Task to task dependency graph. Because sure I was pulling in a few too many jars in some spots... but the real problem was my tasks were depending on each other in stupid ways therefore pulling in pretty much every build task no matter what you built.

And there is a plugin here: https://github.com/mmalohlava/gradle-visteg

Creates graphviz file from your deps. Then you can use graphviz to render to image to see a picture of what's going on.